# Comparable Sort Numbers Java

Tags: java

This is my complete program

```
 public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        ArrayList < Student > studentsList = new ArrayList <> ();

        Student std1 = new Student("Ram","01-01-1981","1203");
        Student std2 = new Student("Raj","01-01-1981","1204");
        Student std3 = new Student("Hanish","01-01-1981","403");
        Student std4 = new Student("Hanish","01-01-1981","");

        studentsList.add(std1);
        studentsList.add(std2);
        studentsList.add(std3);
        studentsList.add(std4);

        Collections.sort(studentsList);
        System.out.println(studentsList);

    }
}
```

When i print i see that the GL Number is not coming in acsending Order

Comment: You're doing a lexical comparison on the `GlNumber`, not a numerical comparison. Lexically, `1204` comes before `403`. Since your code comment states that `GlNumber` is alphanumeric, how do you expect to do a numerical comparison?

Comment: Your output looks correct to me.  Did you intend `GLNumber` to be `Integer`, maybe, instead of `String`?

Comment: `["", "1203", "1204", "403"]` looks like ascending *strings* to me.

Comment: In case these values are alphanumeric as per your code comment: pad all your values with leading zeroes or spaces to a fixed length before doing the comparison. If they are actually numeric instead of alphanumeric, convert to an `Integer` or `Long`.

Comment: @Hanish - I've already told you how to fix it.  You intended `GLNumber` to be an `Integer`, not a `String`.

Comment: I consider storing the date of joining as a `String` in your objects a design error. Store `LocalDate` objects. Only convert to `String` when you need to give string output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are comparing the **String** GlNumber, not the number it represents. You state in the code that GLNumber is alphanumeric, so I think it's fair to say that your comparator works to spec.

`"1204" < "403"`

`1204 > 403`

On a side note: why store studentDOJ as String too? Seems like it should be `java.time.LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your **glNumber** is in String and You want numerical ascending.

You can understand the problem using the following examples

**Sample 1**

```
List stringList = Arrays.asList("1","2","10");
Collections.sort(stringList);
System.out.println(stringList);
// Returns [1, 10, 2]
```

**Sample 2**

```
List numberList = Arrays.asList(1,2,10);
Collections.sort(numberList);
System.out.println(numberList);
// Returns [1, 2, 10]
```

Now, the **solution** to your problem. Try below **compareTo(...)**

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student other) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    return Comparator.comparing((Student student) -> LocalDate.parse(student.getStudentDOJ(), formatter)).reversed()
            .thenComparingLong(student -> student.getGlNumber().length() == 0 ? 0 : Long.valueOf(student.getGlNumber()))
            .compare(this, other);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create studentDateComparator which implements Comparator as follows:

```
@Override
public int compare(Student a, Student b) {
    // ascending
    // int r = a.getStudentDOJ().compareTo(b.getStudentDOJ());
    // decending
    int r = b.getStudentDOJ().compareTo(a.getStudentDOJ());
    if (r == 0) {
        r = comparison(a, b);
    }
    return r;
}

public int comparison(Student a, Student b) {

    String s1 = a.getGlNumber();
    String s2 = b.getGlNumber();

    String[] pt1 = s1.split("((?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9]))|((?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z]))");
    String[] pt2 = s2.split("((?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9]))|((?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z]))");

    // pt1 and pt2 arrays will have the string split in alphabets and numbers

    int i = 0;
    if (Arrays.equals(pt1, pt2))
        return 0;
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < Math.min(pt1.length, pt2.length); i++)
            if (!pt1[i].equals(pt2[i])) {
                if (!isNumber(pt1[i], pt2[i])) {
                    if (pt1[i].compareTo(pt2[i]) > 0)
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return -1;
                } else {
                    int nu1 = Integer.parseInt(pt1[i]);
                    int nu2 = Integer.parseInt(pt2[i]);
                    if (nu1 > nu2)
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return -1;
                }
            }
    }

    if (pt1.length > i)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

private static Boolean isNumber(String n1, String n2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        int nu1 = Integer.parseInt(n1);
        int nu2 = Integer.parseInt(n2);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception x) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

}

Here is your given class:

```
private String studentName;
private String studentDOJ;
private String GlNumber; // alphanumeric

public Student(String studentName, String date, String glNumber) {
    super();
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.studentDOJ = date;
    GlNumber = glNumber;
}

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}


public String getStudentDOJ() {
    return studentDOJ;
}

public void setStudentDOJ(String studentDOJ) {
    this.studentDOJ = studentDOJ;
}

public String getGlNumber() {
    return GlNumber;
}

public void setGlNumber(String glNumber) {
    GlNumber = glNumber;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [studentName=" + studentName + ", studentDOJ=" + studentDOJ + ", GlNumber="
            + GlNumber + "]";
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Student arg0) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

And your the main method will be like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
    ArrayList<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<>();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    Student std1 = new Student("Ram", "01-01-1981", "1203");
    Student std2 = new Student("Raj", "01-01-1981", "1204");
    Student std3 = new Student("Hanish", "01-01-1981", "403");
    Student std4 = new Student("Hanish", "01-01-1981", "");

    studentsList.add(std1);
    studentsList.add(std2);
    studentsList.add(std3);
    studentsList.add(std4);

    System.out.println(studentsList);

    Collections.sort(studentsList, new studentDateComparator());

    System.out.println(studentsList);

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. I also haven’t spotted the what’s cleaner about your code. The questioner was doing exactly the right thing by using `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thanks @OleV.V. , I've made correction in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use This to get your desired solution.

```
int extractInt(String s) {
        String num = s.replaceAll("\\D", "");
        // return 0 if no digits found
        return num.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(num);
    }

@Override
public int compareTo(Student other) {
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
  return Comparator.comparing((Student student) -> LocalDate.parse(student.getStudentDOJ(), formatter)).reversed()
          .thenComparing(student -> extractInt(student.getGlNumber()))
      .compare(this, other);
}
```

Comment: Your output will be [Student [studentName=Hanish, studentDOJ=01-01-1981, GlNumber=], Student [studentName=Hanish, studentDOJ=01-01-1981, GlNumber=403], Student [studentName=Ram, studentDOJ=01-01-1981, GlNumber=1203], Student [studentName=Raj, studentDOJ=01-01-1981, GlNumber=1204]]